# c# WebClient Post returns Server returns 500 but restclient is working

Tags: c#, url, post

This code returns a 500

```
string URL = "http://" + MSSRestSrv + ":8018/Quality/SerialNumbers/BoxBuilds/" + serial + "/Attach/";
string SubAssemblySerialNumber = form.serail;
string Refdes = row.Cells["RefDesc"].Value.ToString().Replace(";", "");

try
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        reqparm.Add("SubAssemblySerialNumber", SubAssemblySerialNumber);
        reqparm.Add("Refdes", Refdes);
        byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", reqparm);
        string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
    }
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    MessageBox.Show(we.Response.ToString());
}
```

But via Chrome and Advanced Rest Client everything is 200 with this URL as POST

http://server:8018/Quality/SerialNumbers/BoxBuilds/999/Attach/?SubAssemblySerialNumber=555&Refdes=SUB1

Any ideas what's the difference?

This is working

```
string SubAssemblySerialNumber = form.serail;
string Refdes = row.Cells["RefDesc"].Value.ToString().Replace(";", "");
string URL = "http://" + MSSRestSrv + ":8018/Quality/SerialNumbers/BoxBuilds/" + serial + "/Attach/?SubAssemblySerialNumber=" + SubAssemblySerialNumber + "&Refdes=" + Refdes + "";
try
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

        byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", reqparm);
        string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
    }
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    MessageBox.Show(we.Response.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The URL you are POSTing to with `UploadValues` does not match the one you have shown in your post.  The query string (the part from the question mark onwards) is not included in the URL you build in your code.

Comment: But isn't that the same as '
`System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        reqparm.Add("SubAssemblySerialNumber", SubAssemblySerialNumber);'
        reqparm.Add("Refdes", Refdes);`

Comment: No it's not the same at all.  The URL is the address that is POSTed to.  The values you upload form part of the POST data that is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin Parkin

is is working

```
string SubAssemblySerialNumber = form.serail;
string Refdes = row.Cells["RefDesc"].Value.ToString().Replace(";", "");
string URL = "http://" + MSSRestSrv + ":8018/Quality/SerialNumbers/BoxBuilds/" + serial + "/Attach/?SubAssemblySerialNumber=" + SubAssemblySerialNumber + "&Refdes=" + Refdes + "";
try
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

        byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", reqparm);
        string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
    }
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    MessageBox.Show(we.Response.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                string cRresultData = wc.UploadString(URI, "POST", CRreq);
                //string cRresultData = wc.UploadString(URI,CRreq);
                string cRresponse = "";

this code gives me  500 Server error
```